# python import modules inside folder

Tags: python

Want to learn the proper way for importing modules with folder

```
/garden
    __init__.py
    utilities.py
    someTools.py
    /plants
        __init__.py
        carrot.py
        corn.py
```

Inside `/plants/__init__.py` I have

```
__all__ = ['carrot', 'corn']
from . import *
```

inside `carrot.py`

```
def info():
    print "I'm in carrot.py"
```

When I do

```
import garden
garden.carrot.info()
# got correct result
I'm in carrot.py
```

My question is how do I correct namespace for `utilities.py` for example inside `carrot.py` and `corn.py`.  I want to use function in `utilities.py`

Inside `carrot.py` when I

```
import utilities as util

# try use it and got global name error
util.someFunc()
# NameError: global name 'util' is not defined #
```

Can I configure `__init__.py` in plants folder so that it import all the modules inside garden? Like utilities and sometools ? so I don't have to import utilities in both carrot.py and corn.py and be able to use utilities ?

Comment: Did you try if `utilities.someFunc()` works? The error is weird because if the interpreter couldn't import it, it should have raised `ImportError`

Comment: Please.. don't `import *`

Answer (score 5):

*note: all `__init__.py` files are empty.*

```
main.py
app/ ->
    __init__.py
    package_a/ ->
       __init__.py
       fun_a.py
    package_b/ ->
       __init__.py
       fun_b.py
```

#### app/package_a/fun_a.py

```
def print_a():
    print 'This is a function in dir package_a'
```

#### app/package_b/fun_b.py

```
from app.package_a.fun_a import print_a
def print_b():
    print 'This is a function in dir package_b'
    print 'going to call a function in dir package_a'
    print '-'*30
    print_a()
```

#### main.py

```
from app.package_b import fun_b
fun_b.print_b()
```

if you run `$ python main.py` it returns:

```
This is a function in dir package_b
going to call a function in dir package_a
------------------------------
This is a function in dir package_a
```

- main.py does: `from app.package_b import fun_b`
- fun_b.py does `from app.package_a.fun_a import print_a`

If you have `app` in your `PYTHONPATH`, then from anywhere you can `>>> from app.package_...`

so file in folder `package_b` used file in folder `package_a`, which is what you want. Right??

Comment: is there a way I can import modules that under app/ for example I want to use main.func() in both fun_a and fun_b.  Instead if import main in each file can I do something in __init__ like import main as main so that in fun_a or fun_b I don't have to import main as main again and be able to use main.func() ??